# How do I debug why Gradle is using a different version of the library I specified in a dependent sub-project?

Tags: gradle, jooq

I have a Gradle build that splits up my JOOQ generated code into a separate `jooq` subproject that my `api-svc` project then depends on.

When I upgrade the `jooq` subproject to `3.10.1`, for some reason Gradle decides to use `3.9.5` to build the `api-svc` instead.  I have no idea why, and I have to override by adding an explicit dependency in my `api-svc` project to work around it.

How can I debug what's going on to see why Gradle is overriding the version?

My JOOQ subproject's definition:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
    ...
    classpath 'org.jooq:jooq-codegen:3.10.1'
    ... 
  }
}
...
dependencies {
  compile 'org.jooq:jooq:3.10.1'
}
...
```

Here's the full version of the `jooq` subproject: https://bitbucket.org/snippets/shorn/64RnL5

And the inclusion in the `api-svc` project:

```
dependencies {
  compile project(":idl")
  compile project(":api-svc:jooq")
  ...
  various other compile dependencies, spring-boot, etc.
```

When I do `./gradlew :api-svc:jooq:dependencies`, it says:

```
  ------------------------------------------------------------
  Project :api-svc:jooq
  ------------------------------------------------------------
  ...
  compile - Dependencies for source set 'main' (deprecated, use 'implementation ' instead).
  \--- org.jooq:jooq:3.10.1
  ...
```

But, when I do `./gradlew :api-svc:dependencies`, it shows:

```
  ------------------------------------------------------------
  Project :api-svc
  ------------------------------------------------------------
  ...
  compile - Dependencies for source set 'main' (deprecated, use 'implementation ' instead).
  +--- project :idl
  |    +--- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4
  |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:2.8.8
  |         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.8.8 -> 2.8.10
  |         \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.8 -> 2.8.10
  |              +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.8.0
  |              \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.8.10
  +--- project :api-svc:jooq
  |    \--- org.jooq:jooq:3.10.1 -> 3.9.5
  ...
```

Full output here, if it helps: https://bitbucket.org/snippets/shorn/4x8eaG

So, you can see Gradle is choosing to use the `3.9.5` version of JOOQ instead of what I specified.

How do I debug *why* Gradle is doing that?

I can workaround this by adding `jooq:3.10.1` as a direct compile dependency of the `api-svc` project - but that's redundant and as far as I understand, I shouldn't have to do that.

**EDIT**: Lukas Eder has pointed out in the comments that the root cause of the problem is the Spring has a dependency on JOOQ 3.9.5 and Gradle is using that.  But the question is - how do I figure that out for myself without trawling through every dependency in my project, just in case they happen to have the reference that's messing up my build?

Comment: Are you using the Gradle jOOQ Plugin?

Comment: @LukasEder No, apparently.  Here is a copy of the jooq project: https://bitbucket.org/snippets/shorn/64RnL5

Comment: I see, so you have some version of Spring Boot on your dependency path. They in turn have a dependency on a specific jOOQ version. Their dependency was upgraded to 3.10.1 only recently: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/10677. But you probably shouldn't depend on their dependency but use your own. I don't know Gradle well enough, unfortunately, to see why the default is overriding your specific version...

Comment: @LukasEder How did you figure out that Spring has a JOOQ dependency though? (or is that just something you happen to know already because you're the JOOQ guy?)

Comment: 1) I've seen this issue before, don't know where. 2) jOOQ is part of the Spring Boot starters: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html#boot-features-jooq

Comment: Spring's [dependency-management-plugin](https://github.com/spring-gradle-plugins/dependency-management-plugin/) might be forcing the version to theirs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a post over on the Gradle forms to try and get an answer to this: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-do-i-debug-why-a-dependency-was-overridden/24572

There was some other discussion in private messages, but my conclusion is that Gradle has no way to debug these kind of dependency overrides.

If you found this question while trying to figure out a problem with your own build - the only advice seems to be that you need to dig through all your dependencies looking for the source of the conflict.

Alternatively, try a StackOverflow question or posting over on the Gradle forums.